# PHP PDO Prepared Statement with table names

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im about to code my own small content management system for my customers and their personal websites. However, I try to submit a prepared mysql statement via PDO through my php code with variables inside.

**Here is an example of my php code:**

```
$PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=".$_SESSION['mysql_host'].";dbname=".$_SESSION['mysql_database'], $_SESSION['mysql_user'], $_SESSION['mysql_password']);
$PDO->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$script = file_get_contents("sql/create_tables.sql");
$stmt = $PDO->prepare(''.$script.''); 
$setprefix = $_SESSION['mysql_prefix'];
$stmt->bindParam(':setprefix', $setprefix);
$stmt->execute();
```

**And here is an exmaple from "create_tables.sql":**

```
CREATE TABLE :prefix_login_attempts (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The result should be, that it creates a table with the name "wc_login_attempts", if the "prefix" was declared as "wc" before, inside a form.

This code is a snippet outside of my installation routine, where my customers should be able to declare a table prefix for their mysql tables being created.

Whats the best way to get this working?
Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Use simple `str_replace`/`sprintf`

Comment: Prepared statement are only to escape values, not to do string replacement. I think you'll need your own format for example `%MY_PREFIX%_login_attempts` and use `str_replace` to replace them before executing the SQL statement.

Comment: where are you getting these `$_SESSION['mysql_host'].";dbname=".$_SESSION['mysql_database'], $_SESSION['mysql_user'], $_SESSION['mysql_password']` ?

Comment: @this.lau_ Sometimes, things are so simple... Thanks alot and also thanks to@u_mulder for that hint! It works ;)